# how to add extensions to vendor manually in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i want to add https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper in yii2 .

i copyed vendor from  instagram-php-scraper  project to yii2's vendor

this is my error :

> Class 'InstagramScraper\Instagram' not found

project extensions(instagram-php-scraper)  is not developed for yii2 .

What other changes should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have have used composer to install Yii2;

Use composer to add the required package:

`composer require raiym/instagram-php-scraper`

See also :

https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper#installation

This way, the classes will be added to composer autoload functionality

Answer (score 1):

Edit `composer.json` file and add your extensions in `require` save and run `composer update` in `cmd`

```
    "require": {
        .
        .
        .
        "raiym/instagram-php-scraper": "^0.8.24"
    },
```